# applicationcraft style properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, applicationcraft

I will try to apply css style for applicationcraft textbox. If I change directly in applicationcraft, it is working. Instead of that If I have upload css code and gave that css class name in custom css class, its not affecting on textbox. I following code I am using,

```
.textbox {
  font-size :  26px !important;
  font-family : Verdana;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(232, 26, 26);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 22px;
  top: 88px;
  left: 128px;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}
```

I have given that class name "textbox" in custom css class. But it is not working. Will you please tell me how can I give css style to textbox.

[image]

Please look at the image. Here I have mention the class name in corresponding place. Next I have saved the file and check the result in live. The style is not affecting in textbox. How to give the style to textbox

Comment: Have you tried debugging the problem e.g. using Chrome Developer Tools? That way, you should be able to figure out if your style is actually applied, if anything is overwriting it, etc. etc.

Comment: Can you create fiddle for it?

Comment: If I  check in chrome developer tool it is working. And I'll copy the same code paste in one notepad. And I upload that file in application craft it is not working.

Comment: Hi  ketan I'm sorry this is new functionality for me. Here I don't know how to create a fiddle.

Comment: @sathishkumar You can create [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/) .